# How to determine transaction fees using web3.py

Tags: transactions, gas, web3.py, gas-price

I am using [web3py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html) to transfer tokens and ether. I need to track the transaction fees for each transaction. Given a transaction hash, how do I determine the total fee paid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get this from the transaction receipt. You can use

```
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transaction_hash)
```

It returns a dictionary with the field `gasused`, combining this with the `gasPrice` that you used for the transaction you can get the fee cost in Ether.

for details of the receipt see the **[Documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?highlight=receipt#web3.eth.Eth.getTransactionReceipt)**

Hope this helps

Comment: So it means, transaction_fee_in_wei = gasUsed * gasPrice ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 5):

The total transaction fee is calculated as `(gasPrice * gasUsed)`. The following example shows how to obtain these values using `web3.py`:

```py
gas_price = web3.eth.getTransaction(transaction_hash).gasPrice
gas_used = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transaction_hash).gasUsed

transaction_cost = gas_price * gas_used
```

The value of `transaction_cost` is denominated in wei.

Related documentation:

- [web3.eth.getTransaction](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.getTransaction)
- [web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.getTransactionReceipt)